# how to display time range slider in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

can any one give idea for how to display time range slider in angularjs

[image: example image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

[Datetime Range Picker](http://rgkevin.github.io/datetimeRangePicker/#/home)
[image]